# Binding DataTable To DataGrid: StringFormat Doesn't Change View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatable

I am binding a DataTable to a DataGrid, and setting the stringformat in the ItemsSource binding. However, the format of the variables in my datagrid don't reflect the changed stringformat, and no error is given. I am implementing a MVVM pattern, using GalaSoft's MVVM Light framework.

My datagrid in the MainWindow looks like this:`

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="grid_Correlation"  
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding correlationmatrix,StringFormat=p}"
                            CanUserAddRows="False" 
                            CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                            CanUserSortColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            SelectionUnit="Cell" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" 
                            EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

`

The MainViewModel class where the table is created, etc. looks as follows:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private DataTable _correlationmatrix;

    public DataTable correlationmatrix
    {
        get { return this._correlationmatrix; }
        set { this.Set("correlationmatrix", ref this._correlationmatrix, value); }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {

        _correlationmatrix = new DataTable();       

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
            col.ColumnName = "Col " + i.ToString();
            col.DataType = typeof(Double);
            _correlationmatrix.Columns.Add(col);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = _correlationmatrix.NewRow();
            _correlationmatrix.Rows.Add(row);

        }

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            {
                _correlationmatrix.Rows[row][col] = 0.5;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

When I execute the code, the DataTable is bound to the datagrid as expected. However, none of the values are formatted as a percentage.

What is it that I am missing?

Thanks!